# AltGr+C does not work, all other combinations work

Tags: windows, keyboard, amd-catalyst, modifier-keys

Key combination <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does nothing in any of my keyboard layouts where it is supposed to enter a special character (example: Polish Programmers layout is supposed to insert `ć`). All other <kbd>AltGr</kbd> combinations do work, including <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (which inserts `Ć` in the Polish layout).

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

I am running Windows 7 on a Dell Studio XPS.

My graphics card is ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5730.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATI Catalyst video card software [may be the culprit](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01552027&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=120&prodSeriesId=3688868&prodTypeId=321957). In this case, you should open Catalyst Control Center and disable „hotkeys” there.

Answer (score -2):

> ATI Catalyst video card software may be the culprit. In this case, you should open Catalyst Control Center and disable „hotkeys” there.

Disabling „hotkeys” there was not enough. Even I disabled, problem remained. After I deleted short cut, it was solved...